# Must declaret the scalar variable exec

Tags: sql, declare

> ```
> USE [Kn_online]
> ```
>
> GO
>   /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LOAD_KNIGHTS_SIEGE_WARFARE_USERS]    Script Date: 04/12/2014 13:51:24 ******/
>   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
>   GO
>   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
>   GO
>   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOAD_KNIGHTS_SIEGE_WARFARE_USERS]
>   @strUserId char(25)
>   AS
>   /*
>   Author : AKUMA
>   Update : 25.10.2009 - 14:23
>   */
>   DECLARE @Knights smallint
>   DECLARE @MasterKnightsID smallint
>   DECLARE @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime datetime
>   DECLARE @AddedLoyalty int
>   DECLARE @IsOnline tinyint
>   SET @AddedLoyalty = 25
>   SELECT @Knights = Knights FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>   SELECT @MasterKnightsID = sMasterKnights FROM KNIGHTS_SIEGE_WARFARE WHERE sCastleIndex = 1
>   IF (@Knights <> 0) AND (@Knights = @MasterKnightsID)
>   BEGIN
>   SELECT @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>   IF DATEDIFF(day,@CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime,GETDATE()) >= 1
>    UPDATE USERDATA SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>   ELSE IF @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime IS NULL
>    UPDATE USERDATA SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>   DECLARE KSWU_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
>   SELECT strUserId FROM USERDATA WHERE Knights = @MasterKnightsID
>   OPEN KSWU_CURSOR
>   FETCH NEXT FROM KSWU_CURSOR INTO @strUserId
>   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
>   BEGIN
>   SET @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = 0
>   SET @IsOnline = 0
>   SELECT @IsOnline = COUNT(strCharID) FROM CURRENTUSER WHERE strCharID = @strUserId
>   IF @IsOnline = 0
>   BEGIN
>    SELECT @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>    IF DATEDIFF(day,@CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime,GETDATE()) >= 1
>     UPDATE USERDATA SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>    ELSE IF @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime IS NULL
>     UPDATE USERDATA SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
>   END
>    FETCH NEXT FROM KSWU_CURSOR INTO @strUserId
>   END
>   CLOSE KSWU_CURSOR
>   DEALLOCATE KSWU_CURSOR
>   END

EXEC LOAD_KNIGHTS_SIEGE_WARFARE_USERS @strUserid

when i use it in other procedure error: must declare the scalar variable

Answer (score 0):

What a messy query, by the way you missed an `END` in your query, test it as below and let me know the result

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOAD_KNIGHTS_SIEGE_WARFARE_USERS] @strUserId char(25) AS DECLARE @Knights smallint DECLARE @MasterKnightsID smallint DECLARE @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime datetime DECLARE @AddedLoyalty int DECLARE @IsOnline tinyint
SET @AddedLoyalty = 25
SELECT @Knights = Knights
FROM USERDATA
WHERE strUserId = @strUserId
  SELECT @MasterKnightsID = sMasterKnights
  FROM KNIGHTS_SIEGE_WARFARE WHERE sCastleIndex = 1 
  IF (@Knights <> 0) AND (@Knights = @MasterKnightsID) 
  BEGIN
      SELECT @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime
      FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserId IF DATEDIFF(DAY,@CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime,GETDATE()) >= 1
      UPDATE USERDATA
      SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,
          CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() 
      WHERE strUserId = @strUserId 
--This END is missing in your code
  END
  ELSE IF @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime IS NULL
      UPDATE USERDATA
      SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,
          CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId 
------------------------------------------------------
  DECLARE KSWU_CURSOR
  CURSOR
  FOR
  SELECT strUserId
      FROM USERDATA WHERE Knights = @MasterKnightsID 
  OPEN KSWU_CURSOR 
  FETCH NEXT FROM KSWU_CURSOR INTO @strUserId 
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN
      SET @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = 0
      SET @IsOnline = 0
      SELECT @IsOnline = COUNT(strCharID)
      FROM CURRENTUSER WHERE strCharID = @strUserId 
      IF @IsOnline = 0 
      BEGIN
          SELECT @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime
          FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = @strUserId 
          IF DATEDIFF(DAY,@CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime,GETDATE()) >= 1
              UPDATE USERDATA
              SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,
                  CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId 
          ELSE IF @CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime IS NULL
              UPDATE USERDATA
              SET Loyalty = Loyalty + @AddedLoyalty,
                  CSWFreeLoyaltyUpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE strUserId = @strUserId 
      END 
      FETCH NEXT FROM KSWU_CURSOR INTO @strUserId 
  END 
  CLOSE KSWU_CURSOR 
  DEALLOCATE KSWU_CURSOR 
END
```